# Matching strings that contain a letter with the first character not being a number

Tags: ruby, regex, string

How do I write a regular expression that has at least one letter, but the first character must not be a number? I tried this

```
str = "a"
str =~ /^[^\d][[:space:]]*[a-z]*/i
# => 0 

str = "="
str =~ /^[^\d][[:space:]]*[a-z]*/i
# => 0
```

The `"=" is matched even though it contains no letters. I expect the`"a"`to match, and similarly a string like`"3abcde"` should not match.

Comment: `[a-z]*` and `[[:space:]]*` can match an empty string and `=` is not  a digit, it is matched with `[^\d]`. Try `/\A(?!\d).*[a-zA-Z].*\z/m` or even `/\A(?!\d).*\p{L}.*\z/m`

Comment: Another way is `str[0] !~ /\d/ && str =~ /[[:alpha]]/ #=> 4` (truthy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[a-z]*` and `[[:space:]]*` patterns can match an empty string, so they do not really make any difference when *validating* is necessary. Also, `=` is not a digit, it is matched with `[^\d]` negated character class that is a *consuming* type of pattern. It means it requires a character other than a digit in the string.

You may rely on a lookahead that will restrict the start of string position:

```
/\A(?!\d).*[a-z]/im
```

Or even a bit faster and Unicode-friendly version:

```
/\A(?!\d)\P{L}*\p{L}/
```

See the [regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/KlDKQPuKTb)

**Details**:

- `\A` - start of a string
- `(?!\d)` - the first char cannot be a digit
- `\P{L}*` - 0 or more (`*`) chars other than letters
  or
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, including line breaks if `/m` modifier is used)
- `\p{L}` - a letter

The `m` modifier enables the `.` to match line break chars in a Ruby regex.

Use `[a-z]` when you need to restrict the letters to those in ASCII table only. Also, `\p{L}` may be replaced with `[[:alpha:]]` and `\P{L}` with `[^[:alpha:]]`.

Comment: Could you not write `/\A(?!\d).*[a-z]/im` or (possibly faster) `/\A(?!\d).*?[a-z]/im`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland You are correct. This answer includes some redundancies. But I don't think greedy match is faster.

Comment: @sawa, do you mean non-greedy?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Right. You got it.

Comment: Thank you, I was a bit mislead by the matching input length issue stated in OP, and thus was focused on both anchors. I "trimmed" the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If two regular expressions were permitted you could write:

```
def pass_de_test?(str)
  str[0] !~ /\d/ && str =~ /[[:alpha]]/
end

pass_de_test?("*!\n?a>") #=> 4 (truthy)
pass_de_test?("3!\n?a>") #=> false
```

If you want `true` or `false` returned, change the operative line to:

```
str[0] !~ /\d/ && str =~ /[[:alpha]]/) ? true : false
```

or

```
!!(str[0] !~ /\d/ && str =~ /[[:alpha]]/)
```